# Multiple VirtualHosts with wildcards

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a three VirtualHosts.  The second two utilize wildcards.

- `www.example.com`
- `*.sites.example.com` (i.e. foo.sites.example.com)
- `*.*.sites.example.com` (i.e. foo.bar.sites.example.com)

For the second two, I tried:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

and

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.*.example.com
```

Problem is `*.example.com` gobbles up `*.*.example.com`.  As maybe a hack, I put `*.*.example.com` before `*.example.com` in my httpd.conf file.

Is what I did the proper way to do this, or is there a more official way?

Comment: Post to http://serverfault.com/ or someone can maybe migrate the question to there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it the right way.
Apache always takes the first VirtualHost if multiple entries match.

For more information about Virtual Host Matching look at the official documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html